# 闭上 pronounced pei-soeng in Cantonese: just Wang Jie in this song or something more?

Tags: pronunciation, cantonese

In [能否不想你](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi4t_jiwsv4) (lyrics [here](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/08/all-chinese-songs-i-have-met.html)), Wang Jie pronounces (or so it seems to my ear)

> 门若闭上了 变再会无期

as

> Mun joek pei-soeng-liu    bin zoi-wui mou-kei

Is this just this video or is this pronunciation actually in any way widespread, or even another word perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is '门若闭上了 **便**再会无期'

[闭](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/987/) only has one Cantonese Jyutping /bai3/ , and it is never pronounced as /pei3/ . Wang Jie pronounced it wrong.

譬, 屁, 媲, 嬖 all pronounced as /pei3/,  but none of them carry the meaning of 'close'

> [上](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/56/) is pronounced as /soeng6/ when it is used as a noun or an adjective
>
> e.g. upper, superior, previous

~

> 上 is pronounced as /soeng5/ when it is used as a verb or verb particle indicating direction or achievement

'上' in '闭上' is a verb particle indicating achievement (close shut)

therefore '闭上' is pronounced as /**bai3 soeng5**/

Comment: I've heard quite a few non-Native Cantonese speakers mispronouncing /-ai-/ syllables as /-ei-/, probably influenced by Mandarin.